# How to write a plugin for javascript that injects a div (like a popup menu)

Tags: javascript, oop, generics, plugins, popup

I've made a suggestion box and I would like to extrapolate it and turn it into reuseable code (a plugin) so I can use it more than once on a page and anywhere. The thing is, I have no idea about how to go about it.

Rather than showing my code, as it is quite large, **what I *would like* to see** is an example code of a plugin that can create a pop-up div over an object when the mouse is over it **AND** it is made in such a way so that it can be used more than once on a page (so it does not use id's).

I would very much appreciate this as it would enlighten me as to how I can begin to go about making my code into a reuseable plugin.

Comment: the fundementals of javascript alone would be enough to inspire your own creation of something so simple.

Comment: If it's so easy, why not give me a viable answer to my question? Is not the point of StackOverFlow to share knowledge instead of sending questioneers packing with euphemisms implying "figure it out yourself"?

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd The point of StackOverflow is not to make the job of someone else. You can easily find your answer on Google. We are not your personal army. What have you actualy tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @Ghilled Please, I am not trying to be rude in any manner. I don't understand and that's why I am writing a question. I am not asking anybody to write a plugin for me. Is it wrong to ask a question? I have done my homework and infact I tried another method in creating a plugin, in the form of making a javascript object with methods, but I did not know how to get it to create its own divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility which should get you started:

```
(function(w, d) {
    function createPopup(el, options) {
        // Create popup from DOM elements, a string, or read from a template
        var popup = d.createElement('div');
        popup.className = options.className;
        popup.innerText = 'Foobar!';
        // Possibly insert popup into DOM, depending on how you've implemented it
        el.parentNode.insertAfter(popup, el);
    }

    var defaultOptions = {
        className: 'popup'
    };

    var MyPlugin = function(el, options) {
        this.element = el;
        this.options = options || defaultOptions;
        this.popup = createPopup(el, this.options);

        var self = this;

        // Ignoring IE for now
        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            self.popup.style.display = 'block';
            // Possibly want to set position of popup, depending on how you've implemented it
        });

        self.popup.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            self.popup.style.display = 'none';
        });
    };

    MyPlugin.prototype = {
        // Other methods you want an instance of MyPlugin to have, for example:
        setText: function(text) {
            this.popup.innerText = text;
        }
    };

    // Static methods
    MyPlugin.setDefaults = function(options) {
        defaultOptions = options;
    };

    w.MyPlugin = MyPlugin;
})(window, document);
```

Usage:

```
<script>
var popup1 = new window.MyPlugin(document.getElementById('#foo'));
var popup2 = new window.MyPlugin(document.getElementById('#bar'));
popup2.setText = "I'm another popup!";

MyPlugin.setDefaults({
    className: 'foobar'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you for sharing and for your time. Quite a lot of detail. I will study it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I've take Roryf's code and worked out some bugs. (@Roryf if your code worked fine for you to start, then I must have been doing something wrong :S)

I changed some code so that it worked for me. Many thanks to Roryf for his well written answer. I hope this benefits others looking for a starting point like me.

I've put a fiddle so there is no need to copy and paste on your computer.

http://jsfiddle.net/crislivinitup/rdqcf/1/

```
(function(w, d) {
function createPopup(el, options) {
    // Create popup from DOM elements, a string, or read from a template
    var popup = d.createElement('div');

    //*** I haven't been able to get className to work, so I commented it out
    // popup.className = options.className;

    //***popup.innerText = 'Foobar!';
    popup.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin",'Foobar!');
    // Possibly insert popup into DOM, depending on how you've implemented it
    //***el.parentNode.insertAfter(popup, el);
    el.appendChild(popup);

    //**** added to hide div by default
    popup.style.display = 'none';

    //*** added to connect this.popup (from MyPlugin function) to the reference of the created div
    return popup;
}

var defaultOptions = {
    //*** I haven't got className to work, so I just took out the related functions
    className: 'popup'
};

var MyPlugin = function(el, options) {
    this.element = el;
    this.options = options || defaultOptions;
    this.popup = createPopup(el, this.options);

    var self = this;



    // Ignoring IE for now
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        //alert("clicked");
        self.popup.style.display = 'block';
        // Possibly want to set position of popup, depending on how you've implemented it
    });

    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        self.popup.style.display = 'none';
    });


};

MyPlugin.prototype = {
    // Other methods you want an instance of MyPlugin to have, for example:
    setText: function(text) {

        //***I didn't get the innerText to work, so I changed it with synonymous code
        //***this.popup.innerText = text;
        this.popup.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd",text);
    }
};

// Static methods
MyPlugin.setDefaults = function(options) {
    defaultOptions = options;
};

w.MyPlugin = MyPlugin;
})(window, document);
```

Implementation:     *must use on an element that can have childrenNodes, such as a div

```
var popup1 = new window.MyPlugin(document.getElementById("foo"));
var popup2 = new window.MyPlugin(document.getElementById("bar"));
popup1.setText("I'm another popup!");
popup1.setText("keep going");
```